# Ajax call slows down and crashes browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a chat application that uses ajax to get messages from database as below:

```
    setInterval(function () {
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "chat.php",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (response) {
              $(".chat").html(response);
              if (response !== lastResponse) {
                  var audio = new Audio('audio/vibes.mp3')
                  audio.play()
              }
              lastResponse = response
          }
      });
  }, 5000);
```

I am sure the reason is because it calls every 5 seconds. Please is there a fix for this using ajax such that it doesn't slow down the browser?

**Note**: I heard of web-sockets recently and planning to improve the chat app with web-sockets.

I just need a quick fix for now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried server sent events?

Comment: Why you're requesting/sending the complete chat instead of only the new messages?

Comment: @Andreas the chat.php only gets the unread messages from the database

Comment: @ShivamArora please am new to all this. So can you help me on what server sent events are? Thanks very much.

Comment: Server sent events is similar to ajax polling and is inbuilt feature of HTML 5, Try to search for server sent events as it only works when some change occurs unlike your case in which it is executing after every 5s.

Answer (score 2):

Try `Server Sent Events` as the code in it only executes when there is some change in the server unlike your case in which it is executing after every 5 seconds.